# Reading ASCII numbers using "D" instead of "E" for scientific notation using C

Tags: c, string, scanf, scientific-notation, atof

I have a list of numbers which looks like this: `1.234D+1` or `1.234D-02`. I want to read the file using C. The function `atof` will merely ignore the `D` and translate only the mantissa.

The function `fscanf` will not accept the format `'%10.6e'` because it expects an `E` instead of a `D` in the exponent.

When I ran into this problem in Python, I gave up and merely used a string substitution before converting from string to float. **But in C, I am sure there must be another way**.

So, how would you read a file with numbers using `D` instead of `E` for scientific notation? Notice that I do not mean how to read the strings themselves, but rather how to convert them to floats.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of [strtod](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strtod.html) and [strtok](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strtok.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char in[] = "1.234D+1 ABCD 1.234D-02 5\n";
    char *cursor;
    char *endp;
    for ( cursor = strtok(in, " "); cursor; cursor = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
        double d = strtod(cursor, &endp);
        if ( *endp == 'D' ) {
            *endp = 'e';
            d = strtod(cursor, &endp);
        }
        if ( endp != cursor ) {
            printf("%e\n", d);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
E:\> cnv
1.234000e+001
1.234000e-002
5.000000e+000
```

Comment: I am disappointed that C lacks native support for reading scientific notation using `D` instead of `E`. Your proposed code is the closest to a perfect solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Arrieta: I am disappointed it can't parse numbers where the letter Q appears instead of the numeral 0 (zero).  Seems the library designers didn't understand how essential our requirements are for so many programs... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

replace D with E, by looping along string. then `atof`.

Answer (score 0):

Here this function is to replace "D" into "E" in the scientific notation with "D".

```
std::string dToE(string cppstr)
{
    str1.replace(cppstr.find("D"),1,"E");
    return cppstr;
}
```

If the C string for scientific notation is defined by:
    char * cstr = "1.2D+03";
or usually obtained by `strtok` method, which returns C string, then use `atof(dToE(string(cstr)).c_str())` to get the scientific notation with "E".

Since `atof` only accept C style string, you should use `c_str()` string method to convert C++ string into C string.